# How to improve Excel performance in workbook with external links and conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I have 5 workbooks with 540 column x 50 row blocks of data.
I also have a 'roll-up' workbook that lists all this data on a single worksheet with links. There are 6 conditional formatting rules.

The roll-up workbook takes ~30 seconds to update links on open and takes 1-2 seconds each time i modify data and move around the worksheet.

I feel like Excel should be able to work with this data in a performant manner.
Am I doing anything wrong? Should i have set things up differently?

I've tried using arrays of links and individualy linked cells and not noticed a difference.

-- EDIT --

When I remove the conditional formatting, the 30 second refresh takes 1 second. Additionally, some Data Validation dropdowns speed up from 6 seconds to immediate. I'll look at ways of removing the Conditional Formatting (like the VBA idea below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, conditional formatting can really slow a spreadsheet down.  I had one much smaller template that became unusable due a lot of conditional formatting, so I had to redesign it with VBA code instead.  In that case this was workable as the cells didn't change much after the initial set-up, so the script only needs to be run once.  It would not be so workable if the data is likely to change often.

You might consider putting the formatting in a VBA script, depending on how often the data (and hence the formating) is likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in the conditional formatting but rather, it is in the fact that you need to open data from 5 different workbooks. Trying to consolidated those workbooks first would improve the speed. Refreshing data connections takes 30 sec.
Alternatively, instead of a linked cell, try to use designated data connections (as you would in Power Query, for example). This way a refresh wouldn't happen automatically but the responsiveness of the main spreadsheet would improve.